# Modify items of a custom RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create a custom `RecyclerView`.

To begin with, I just want to rotate the first element of the list attached to my `recyclerView`.

Here is what I tried to do by overriding `setAdapter` method:

```
public class CustomList extends RecyclerView {

    public CustomList(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomList(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomList(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
        getChildAt(0).setRotation(45);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayoutManager(LayoutManager layout) {
        super.setLayoutManager(layout);
    }
}
```

But I get this error each time I try to change an element of my list:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setRotation(float)' on a null object reference

I want to get this RecyclerView items one by one to modify them. Is it possible to reach each item of my RecyclerView to add them modifications? Knowing that I'm actually creating a **Custom View extending RecyclerView** and not a **RecyclerView Adapter**.

Answer (score 1):

The app crashes because you are trying to access a view which doesn't exist. When you call `setAdapter` it just creates the adapter object and sets it to the `RecyclerView`. At that time the children have not been created yet, so `getChildAt(0)` returns `null` and you get the crash.

Instead, you should use adapter for item view manipulations. In your adapter override `onBindViewHolder` method and do it there instead. The method is called every time when an item view is bound to the `RecyclerView`. It has a position parameter which you can use for rotating only the first item in the list.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E)

Comment: @GennadiiSparykin Should I make my CustomView extending RecyclerView.Adapter instead and override my onBindViewHolder method?

Comment: I don't think you need a custom `RecyclerView` in this case. Use a regular one. And yes, extend `RecycerView.Adapter` and override `onBindViewHolder` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to create a custom `RecyclerView` in my case, that's my point. I'm creating a library and I want people who use it not to have to add anything to their own `RecyclerView.Adapter` to use it. I want my modifications to work automatically.

Comment: In this case it does not matter if this is a library or not. If you want people to not add anything just expose your `RecyclerView.Adapter` to them. The client who will be using your library will create a normal `RecyclerView`, then call `recyclerView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter());` and will get the rotation functionality. There is no reason to make an empty `RecyclerView` wrapping because there is nothing custom in it. Clients will still have to call `setAdapter` to render the item list.

Comment: But If they have to use my own `RecyclerView.Adapter`, they won't be able to make their own changes to this `Adapter` because it will have already been done.

Comment: The original question doesn't have any information about that.. You should've included that in the first place :) What kind modifications are we talking about? I'm pretty sure they will be able to do modifications to the adapter by extending your adapter. They will be able to override any method they need to.